# Pasta proibida no diretorio de usuario hospedagem

Tags: hospedagem

No diretório de usuário onde fica o public_html tem as seguintes pastas:

```
public_html
.logs
NO_NOT_UPLOAD_HERE
```

O que acontece se eu fizer *upload* lá sendo que tem um arquivo mandando eu não fazer?

Comment: Bemvindo ao Stackoverflow! A diretoria chama-se mesmo `NO_NOT_UPLOAD_HERE`? Que tipo de servidor/serviço é? Podes especificar mais? Provavelmente é uma pasta que é apagada frequentemente ou tem permissões que podem pôr em perigo o teu site se utilizadores puderem correr ficheiros lá...

Comment: é a cpanel da hostinger meu site vive caindo 
Ai eu queria saber se foi pq eu fiz upload no local onde nao pode fazer

Comment: Que tipo de ficheiros colocaste lá? ficheiros que o site usa? que ficheiros tem essa diretoria de inicio?

Comment: Se você fizer upload lá, seu computador irá explodir em mil pedaços, o fio do seu modem irá derreter e seu roteador de internet irá pegar fogo.

Comment: Acredito que seria mas viável você solicitar o suporte da empresa, já que você esta pagando pelo serviço.

Comment: @HiagoSouza esse `hostinger` pelo menos aqui na suécia é gratis.

Comment: @Sergio peço desculpas então, eu o confundi com o hostgator. Mas mesmo assim o hostinger te oferece suporte, mesmo sendo free. Eu mesmo sou cliente deles e tenho alguns VPS online

Comment: @HiagoSouza interessante e tens essa pasta que o AP refere?

Comment: Não, é um servidor VPS. Eu que o configurei, não é compartilhado.

Comment: Se você fizer o upload lá, um meteoro vai cair na Terra, haverá uma guerra nuclear e uma invasão alienígena. Além disso, você corre o risco de ser devorado por um tiranossauro enquanto estiver correndo para tentar fugir do ataque das abelhas mutantes radioativas.